# Options<T> not populating in DI

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, autofac, aggregateroot

I'm using .Net Core 2.1 and an Aggregate / Facade pattern for my dependencies (which I happily do elsewhere using Ninject / .net 4.6). But when I try to pass through options I get a null (Debugging I can see there being picked up) but there not passed to Autofac (I'm fairly sure its my as they weren't when I tried Ninject either).

I've made a simple test project (new .net core web application /2.1) and then added a minimal amount of code to replicate

**Startup.cs**

```cs
    public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });
        services.Configure<ApiEndpointsConfiguration>(Configuration);
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

        // Create the container builder.
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        builder.Populate(services);
        builder.RegisterAggregateService<IViewModelProvider>();

        var assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                            .Where(x => x.FullName.StartsWith("TEST")).ToArray();

        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assemblies)
             .Where(t => t.IsClass)
             .AsImplementedInterfaces()
             .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

        builder.RegisterAggregateService<IDomainServiceProvider>();
        ApplicationContainer = builder.Build();

        var chkOptions = ApplicationContainer.Resolve<IOptions<ApiEndpointsConfiguration>>();


        // Create the IServiceProvider based on the container.
        return new AutofacServiceProvider(ApplicationContainer);
    }
```

**Program.cs**

```cs
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureServices(services => services.AddAutofac())
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
    }
```

**IViewModelProvider.cs**

```
public interface IViewModelProvider
{
    IProgrammeViewModelBuilder ProgrammeViewModel { get; }
}
```

**IProgrammeViewModelBuilder.cs**

```
public interface IProgrammeViewModelBuilder
{
    ProgrammeViewModel GetProgrammeViewModel();
}
```

My initial issue was that in my service, controller calls the injected viewmodelbuilder

```
var viewModel = _viewModels.ProgrammeViewModel.GetProgrammeViewModel();
```

which in turn calls the service -

```
    readonly IOptions<ApiEndpointsConfiguration> _apiSettings;

    public ProgrammeService(IOptions<ApiEndpointsConfiguration> apiSettings) : base (new Uri(apiSettings.Value.BaseAddress))
    {
        _apiSettings = apiSettings;
    }
```

but at that point (the constructor firing) the service configuration items were null so I've stepped through and I can see that services has the values for "ApiEndpointsConfiguration" picked up but when they get passed through to the "builder" the values are null

```
ApplicationContainer.Resolve<IOptions<ApiEndpointsConfiguration>>();
```

shows null for the values inside.

Not sure what it is I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

:( Truly this is when the answer is so much simpler thank it looks. Kudos to anyone who spots it;

```
services.Configure<ApiEndpointsConfiguration>(Configuration.GetSection("ApiEndpointsConfiguration"));
```

rather than

```
services.Configure<ApiEndpointsConfiguration>(Configuration);
```

So essentially whilst I thought I could see it debugging I was seeing the raw JSON provided values not the "configured service". I'll leave this here as a lesson to myself to check the simple things first.

Not sure what what was actually being "registered" in my first effort.

Comment: "Not sure what what was actually being "registered" in my first effort." - well, you were receiving config object with all empty fields. Am I right? So, you _were_ registering your config options object, it's just incorrect data binding that you were using to fill it out.

Comment: Yeah that's exactly it :( I could see the values if I debugged as they were available (just not mapped as you say)